# flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, printing, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

I am using [esc_pos_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils) and trying to print image. It is working fine in android but i am getting the following error in iOS.

```
flutter: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast
[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
```

I am getting this error in iOS when I am trying to get bluetooth devices with following code:

```
Future<void> getBluetooth() async {
    await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
    await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();

    try {
      final List bluetooths = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.getBluetooths; // getting error on this line
      print("Print $bluetooths");
      availableBluetoothDevices = bluetooths;
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I thought it was return type error so it changed the below line but still same error.

```
final List bluetooths = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.getBluetooths;
```

to

```
await BluetoothThermalPrinter.getBluetooths;
```

I have added the following code in my info.plist. When i call the above function is asks for permission successfully but still i am getting error.

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need BLE permission for getting printers</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need BLE permission for getting printers</string>

   <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

I have also added permission in Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
            '$(inherited)',
            ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
            'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1'
          ]
    end
  end
end
```

I have also checked these:
[image]

Comment: availableBluetoothDevices = bluetooths cannot be assigned because the availableBluetoothDevices is a string and bluetooths is not string, it returns a list of dynamic variables.

Comment: @ShafqatNadeem I also tried putting "var" instead of "List" but still same issue. Even I tried removing "final List bluetooths =" but still same

Comment: Did you try "final String bluetooths" instead of "final List bluetooths"?

Comment: @VincentDR no. BluetoothThermalPrinter.getBluetooths has a return type of Future<List<dynamic>>. So we can’t.The issue is that the code is working for android but showing error for iOS. Bascially that line is getting available bluetooth devices

Comment: Can you try `final blueteeth  = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.getBluetooths;` and call print dynamically. If it is  iOS only error maybe getBluetooths method doesn't return List? Can you share the implementation of this method?

Comment: I have mentioned the plugin above. That plugin is using "bluetooth_thermal_printer"plugin to get bluetooth devices. You can see implementation of that plugin here: https://github.com/Rajath4/BluetoothThermalPrinter/blob/master/lib/bluetooth_thermal_printer.dart#:~:text=paired%20bluetooth%20devices-,static%20Future%3CList%3F%3E%20get%20getBluetooths%20async%20%7B,%7D,-///%20Get%20bluetooth%20device